# Search range for specific comments

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search a range for specific text in a all cells with comments. Then change the background color of the cells containing the comment with specified text.

Any help? I'm stuck :(

Comment: As a start, try the first 20 solutions of google for [finding text](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_deAT822AT823&ei=O4R_XPizFbrRmwXXspKgAg&q=excel+vba+search+range+for+specific+text&oq=excel+vba+search+range+for+specific+text&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22396.23074..23225...0.0..0.92.342.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j0i8i30j33i10.ArYYBTXGGGM) and [changing cell color](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+change+cell+color+on+condition&rlz=1C1GCEU_deAT822AT823&oq=excel+vba+change+cell+color+on+condition&aqs=chrome..69i57.12199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-89).

Comment: By "specific text in cells with comments", do you mean the comment text or the cell text?

Comment: Thanks, I mean the comment text. The cell is used simply to indicate something by its color.

Answer (score 0):

The following user-defined function will return the comment text. Put it in a module.

```
Public Function GetComment(Optional rng As Range)
  If rng Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = Application.Caller
  End If
  If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
    GetComment = ""
  Else
    GetComment = rng.Comment.Text
  End If
End Function
```

Then create a conditional format rule with formula `=FIND("your search text",GetComment())>0`.